# Problem with big equations (matrices)

Tags: math-mode

I have used LaTeX for writing my paper. The template of journal is in two columns and I have some problems with breaking large equations (especially matrices). Would you please guide me?

Details:
I have used the `multiline` environment but the brackets related to matrix is small.

In another attempt I used equation environment but `\\` does not work to go from the upper side of matrix to the lower part of the matrix.

I have written the equation in two structures:

1:

```
\begin{equation}\label{eq:eq10}
\left[
\begin{matrix} {\bar A}{x_1} + {\tilde B}{x_2} + {\hat C}{x_3} & {P{{\bar A}_{1i}}} & \cdots \\
* & { - (1 - {\mu _1}){P_1}} & \cdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots \\
* & * & \cdots \\
* & * & \cdots \\
* & * & \cdots
\end{matrix} \\
\qquad \qquad \begin{matrix} {P{{\bar A}_{si}}} & {P{{\bar B}_i}} & {{{\bar C}^T}} \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
{ - (1 - {\mu _s}){P_s}} & 0 & 0 \\
* &{ - {\gamma ^2}I} & {{{\bar D}^T}} \\
* & * & { - I} \end{matrix}
\right] < 0
\end{equation}
```

This solution has the problem that `\\` after first `\end{matrix}` does not work. I mean it does not force the remaining of the equation to go to the next line.

2:

```
\begin{multline}
\Bigg[
%\left(
\begin{matrix} {\bar A}{x_1} + {\tilde B}{x_2} + {\hat C}{x_3} & {P{{\bar A}_{1i}}} & \cdots \\
* & { - (1 - {\mu _1}){P_1}} & \cdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots \\
* & * & \cdots \\
* & * & \cdots \\
* & * & \cdots
\end{matrix} \\
%\right
%\left
\begin{matrix} {P{{\bar A}_{si}}} & {P{{\bar B}_i}} & {{{\bar C}^T}} \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
{ - (1 - {\mu _s}){P_s}} & 0 & 0 \\
* &{ - {\gamma ^2}I} & {{{\bar D}^T}} \\
* & * & { - I} \end{matrix}
\Bigg] < 0
%\right)
\end{multline}
```

This is the second solution. It is well broken in two sub-matrices but it has the problem that the brackets of the matrix are very small for this big matrix, even with the `\Bigg` command.

How should I fix this problem?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You seem to believe that braces are necessary in several places where they aren't: for instance `{ - (1 - {\mu _s}){P_s}}` can and should be typed as `-(1 - \mu_s)P_s` (with or without spaces, which are ignored). Also it should be `\bar{A}`, not `{\bar A}`. Just another example: `{P{{\bar B}_i}}` is, more simply, `P\bar{B}_i`.

Answer (score 3):

If `amsmath` is not forbidden, a solution (rather strange) may be as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}


%\begin{equation}\label{eq:eq10}
\begin{gather}\label{eq:eq10}
\left[
\begin{matrix} {\bar A}{x_1} + {\tilde B}{x_2} + {\hat C}{x_3} & {P{{\bar A}_{1i}}} & \cdots \\
* & { - (1 - {\mu _1}){P_1}} & \cdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots \\
* & * & \cdots \\
* & * & \cdots \\
* & * & \cdots
\end{matrix}
\right.
 \nonumber\\
\qquad \qquad\left. \begin{matrix} {P{{\bar A}_{si}}} & {P{{\bar B}_i}} & {{{\bar C}^T}} \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
{ - (1 - {\mu _s}){P_s}} & 0 & 0 \\
* &{ - {\gamma ^2}I} & {{{\bar D}^T}} \\
* & * & { - I} \end{matrix}
\right] < 0
%\end{equation}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why not `multline`?

Comment: @egreg `multline` or `align` or `gather`... This is a different possibility for OP.